# Saving Levels of a Simple Flash Game?

Tags: flash, save, loading, game-development

With special thanks to **JoãoCésar** This as3 code creates a function to generate the SWF loader. He used an incremental value (count) to iterate in loop through an array that stores the dynamic infos of each loader. In this case, count % swfs.length will result in 0, 1, 0, 1... Effectively loading the SWFs in a loop sequence.

So here is the IDEA :

How can I save or remember, last time which swf file is closed and next time you just start from that one... (It should remembers which swf is finished and next time you will start from that one instead of child1.swf )

For this I used SharedObject and tried to save number of swf file that is just loaded in a variable ,but I can't handle it in correct way...

Thanks

Here is the Code :

```
import com.greensock.*;  
import com.greensock.loading.*;  
import com.greensock.events.LoaderEvent;  
import flash.display.DisplayObjectContainer;  
import flash.events.Event;  

var count:uint = 0;  
var currentSWFLoader:SWFLoader;  
var swf:Object = {};  
var swfs:Array =   
[  
    {path:"child1.swf", container:this},  
    {path:"child2.swf", container:this}  
]  

function generateSWFLoader(path:String, container:DisplayObjectContainer):SWFLoader  
{  
    return new SWFLoader  
    (  
        path,  
        {  
            container: container,  
            y:         100,  
            onProgress:progressHandler,  
            onComplete:completeHandler,  
            autoPlay:  false  
        }  
    );  
}  

function loadSWF(index:uint):void  
{  
    if (currentSWFLoader)  
        currentSWFLoader.dispose(true);  

    swf = swfs[index];  
    currentSWFLoader = generateSWFLoader(swf.path, swf.container);  
    currentSWFLoader.load();  
}  

function progressHandler(e:LoaderEvent):void  
{  
    bar.scaleX = e.target.progress;  
}  

function completeHandler(e:LoaderEvent):void  
{  
    e.target.rawContent.play();  
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkFrame);  
}  

function checkFrame(e:Event):void  
{  
    if (currentSWFLoader.rawContent.currentFrame == currentSWFLoader.rawContent.totalFrames)  
    {  
        trace("swf done playing");  
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkFrame);  
        loadSWF(++count % swfs.length);      
    }  
}  

bar.scaleX = 0;  
loadSWF(count % swfs.length);
```

Comment: Store the **count** variable with the **SharedObject**.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some general info on how to save a variable in a shared object.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    //import the shared object
    import flash.net.SharedObject;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        //create and store the shared object
        var my_so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("yourNameOfSharedObject");

        public function Main() 
        {
            //un-comment to save or load
            //save();
            //load();


        }

        function save(){
            //save the number 2 to the shared object in a variable called swfNumber
            my_so.data.swfNumber = 2;
        }

        function load(){
            //load the the number stored in swfNumber
            var swfNumber = my_so.data.swfNumber;
            trace(swfNumber);
        }
    }
}
```